# Saving to Table Field Type via Plugin

Tags: plugin-development, table-field

I keep getting a server error when attempting to save data to a table field. This is the code I am using test data insertion. (251 is a valid enteryId)

```
    $entry = craft()->entries->getEntryById(251, $localeId = null);
    $arr = array('col1' => 'some sku', 'col2' => 'This is a big fat description', 'col3' => 495.00, 'col4' => 0);
    $arr = json_encode($arr);
    $entry->getContent()->gistDistribution = $arr;
    $success = craft()->entries->saveEntry($entry);
```

This is my error:

```
Internal Server Error
Illegal string offset 'sku'
```

Note: sku is a column name in my table field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NOT TESTED

1. I think you can just add an array to gistDistribution, it will get
   json_encoded before saving.
2. I think you'd have to set the variable like this:

   `$arr[0] = array(...);`

That way, you provide a multidimensional array, which is what a table needs.

Comment: I have tested your recommendations. It works. To add a row. 
$arr[0] = array(...);
$existingDistributions = $entry->getContent()->gistDistribution;
array_push($existingDistributions, $arr[0]);